# How to get a value less than INT_MIN?

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:
    int thirdMax(vector<int>& nums) 
    {
        int first = INT_MIN;
        int second = INT_MIN;
        int third = INT_MIN;
        
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++)
        {
            if(nums[i] > first)
            {
                third = second;
                second = first;
                first = nums[i];
            }
            else if(nums[i] > second && nums[i] != first)
            {
                third = second;
                second = nums[i];
            }
            else if(nums[i] > third && nums[i] != first && nums[i] != second)
            {
                third = nums[i];
            }
        }
        
        if(third == INT_MIN)
            return first;
        else
            return third;
    }
};
```

This code is to find the third largest number and if it does not exist, then return the first largest number. Most of the test cases are successful but how do I use this method for
[1,2,-2147483648] where one of the array elements itself is INT_MIN?

Comment: The title does not match the question. The title wants a value less than `INT_MIN` which can't fit in an `int` but the question asks about using exactly `INT_MIN`.

Comment: `How to get a value less than INT_MIN?` By using a signed type with wider range of representable values than `int`.

Comment: Formulate a condition based on the number of distinct numbers rather than their values.

Comment: A simple approach is to set the first three values from the array as the current maximums.  You can then order those and run your loop as normal after.  Or, consider using `>=` (instead of `>` which you're currently using) which is probably more correct anyway.

Comment: @paddy IMHO that's the better solution than adding all this complexity with `optional` suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid "imbuing" `INT_MIN` with a special meaning, and instead use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). This class is intended to distinguish the case of "no value" or "empty", from an actual value.

With optionals, you can express what you actually want to check explicitly, i.e. not whether or not a number is greater or smaller than `INT_MIN`, but rather whether you already have a "first greatest", "second greatest" etc.

```
int third_highest(const::vector<int>& nums) 
{
    std::optional<int> highest[3];

    if (nums.empty()) { 
        throw std::invalid_argument("Expected a non-empty sequence of integers");
    }
    
    for(auto x : nums) {
        if (not highest[0].has_value()) { highest[0] = x; continue; }
        if (x > highest[0].value()) {
            highest[2] = highest[1];
            highest[1] = highest[0];
            highest[0] = x;
            continue;
        }
        if (not highest[1].has_value()) { highest[1] = x; continue; }
        if (x > highest[1].value()) {
            highest[2] = highest[1];
            highest[1] = x;
            continue;
        }
        if (not highest[2].has_value()) { highest[2] = x; continue; }
        if (x > highest[2].value()) {
            highest[2] = x;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return highest[2] ? highest[2].value() : highest[0].value(); 
}
```

... and actually, this can be simplified and shortened further if you loop over the `highest` values; or if you make `highest` a small vector whose size gradually increases from 0 up to 3.

---

<sub>PS - You should not use a "Solution class". It is a bad idea to wrap functions in classes for no reason.</sub>

Comment: the reason is probably leetcode that has such template for the solutions. I am not getting tired of explaining to leeters that they better write proper code for testing and debugging (and only for submission use the template)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yeah, it appears to be so: https://leetcode.com/problems/third-maximum-number/

Comment: @Bob__ unfortunately they have a `using namespace std;` in the hidden part, which can lead to all kinds of problems.

Comment: @idclev463035818: Interesting, and sad, to know. I guess they really teach you to be a 7331 h4x0r...

Answer (score 2):

I would check whether the size of the vector is < 3 instead of checking if third is INT_MIN

```
if(nums.size() < 3)
            return first;
        else
            return third;
```

Edit:
So I realize that your code isn't counting repeated values. My solution to that would be adding a counter to keep track of how many unique elements there are, and then check whether there are at least 3 unique values or not

```
class Solution {
public:
    int thirdMax(vector<int>& nums) 
    {
        int first = INT_MIN;
        int second = INT_MIN;
        int third = INT_MIN;
        int counter = 0;
        
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++)
        {
            if(nums[i] > first)
            {
                third = second;
                second = first;
                first = nums[i];
                counter++;
            }
            else if(nums[i] > second && nums[i] != first)
            {
                third = second;
                second = nums[i];
                counter++;
            }
            else if(nums[i] > third && nums[i] != first && nums[i] != second)
            {
                third = nums[i];
                counter++;
            }
        }
        
        if(counter < 3)
            return first;
        else
            return third;
    }
};
```

Comment: What if the vector contains only many values, but only two distinct ones?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a value smaller than `INT_MIN`. There is no `int` smaller than `INT_MIN`.

Your actual problem can be solved by sorting the vector in decreasing order (assuming you are fine with a `O(n log n)` solution):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int thirdMax(std::vector<int>& nums) {
    // trivial cases
    if (nums.size() == 0) return -42; // or throw an exception ?
    if (nums.size() == 1) return nums[0];
    // sort
    std::sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),std::greater<int>());
    // third largest
    if (nums.size() > 2) return nums[2];
    // otherwise largest
    return nums[0];
}
```

Comment: `std::nth_element` could be more efficient here, as I understand. but you would need to check the size of the array is 3 or more.

Comment: @JHBonarius yeah, I considered to add a linear version. The current one was focusing on simplicity only

Comment: @JHBonarius *If* the problem the OP are trying to solve is [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/third-maximum-number/), they mention *distinct* numbers, though.

Comment: @Bob__ good point... I posted my own solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

I want to propose another solution, to only use distinct values, like the question asks

(ab)Use a `std::set`!

```
#include<vector>
#include<set>
#include<functional>
#include<iterator>

class Solution {
public:
    int thirdMax(std::vector<int> const& nums) {
        if (nums.size() == 0) return -42; // I like this one.
        std::set<int, std::greater<int>> s(cbegin(nums), cend(nums));
        if (s.size() > 2) return *next(cbegin(s),2);
        return *cbegin(s);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is using existance flags.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int thirdMax(vector<int>& nums) 
    {
        int first = INT_MIN;
        int second = INT_MIN;
        int third = INT_MIN;
        bool firstExists = false, secondExists = false, thirdExists = false;
        
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++)
        {
            if(!firstExists || nums[i] > first)
            {
                third = second;
                second = first;
                first = nums[i];
                firstExists = true;
            }
            else if((!secondExists || nums[i] > second) && nums[i] != first)
            {
                third = second;
                second = nums[i];
                secondExists = true;
            }
            else if((!thirdExists || nums[i] > third) && nums[i] != first && nums[i] != second)
            {
                third = nums[i];
                thirdExists = true;
            }
        }
        
        if(!thirdExists)
            return first;
        else
            return third;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the whole `int` domain, using a magic number like `INT_MIN` is not going to work correctly.

Using `std::optional<int>` as the type for `first`, `second`, and `third` is the solution here.

Adjust the conditionals accordingly: `if (first)` evaluates to `true` if and only if `first` has an explicit value set, and use `*first` to access the value if it has an explicit value set.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the given solutions won't work or are suggesting O(n*logn) time.

One solution suggests to use a counter and check if its greater than 3 while another one suggested to use existence flag. However, both of these solutions are not ideal since your given code will only update their counter variables when nums[i] > third. But since, nums[i] == INT_MIN this condition won't match and the counter/flag will not get updated. Even if you keep the condition as nums[i] > third for the third condition, your code will fail for a case like [-2147483648, 1, 2].

Hence, I suggest my solution where you just check if you have encountered INT_MIN in the array or not and then return maximum or third maximum value accordingly:

```
    int thirdMax(vector<int>& nums) {
        int max1= INT_MIN, max2 = INT_MIN, max3 = INT_MIN;
        bool notEncounteredMin = true;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++){
            if (nums[i] == INT_MIN) {
                notEncounteredMin = false;
            }
            if(nums[i] > max1){
                max3= max2;
                max2= max1;
                max1= nums[i];
            }
            else if(nums[i] > max2 && nums[i]< max1){
                max3 = max2;
                max2 = nums[i];
            }
            else if(nums[i] >= max3 && nums[i] < max2){
                max3 = nums[i];
            }
        }
        if(max3 == INT_MIN && notEncounteredMin) 
            return max1;
        return max3;
    }
```